# PHP built in array function

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Lets say I end up with an array like such:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => user 
                       [1] => pass
                     ) 
)
```

maybe as a result of passing an array through a function and using `func_get_args()`

In this case, I would want to get rid of the initial array, so I just end up with:

```
Array ( [0] => user 
        [1] => pass
)
```

I know I could make a function to accomplish this, and push each element into a new array, however, is there some built in functionality with PHP that can pull this off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$new_array = $old_array[0];
```

...

Answer (score 5):

[`array_pop()`](http://php.net/array_pop) will pop the last (first, if only 1 is present) element.

Comment: why would you use a function to access a directly accessible member of the single element array?

Comment: Scared of hardcoding indexes :D

Answer (score 1):

Just take the value of the first element of the "outer" array.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [array_shift](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) as it removes and returns the first element off of the *beginning* of the array.